# Slow broker in ActiveMQ 5.6

Tags: performance, response, activemq-classic, scheduler, broker

We have recently migrated from ActiveMQ 4.0 to ActiveMQ 5.6 and are noticing a slowing down of response time from broker by around 50-60 seconds. We are using the default ActiveMQ 5.6 setup and have not configured any paramter. Client is using Java Impl stubs and application server is Jboss 5.1.0. We turned on TRACE logging in ActiveMQ to check the reason for the slowing down but are not able to find anything significant. The queue looks like it is waiting for some reason and we can see a lot of the following lines repeated in the log:

```
2012-06-11 02:04:38,523 | DEBUG | queue://dav/validator expiring messages .. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:38,524 | DEBUG | dav/validator toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 0, dequeueCount: 0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:38,524 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@e0420b:dav/validator,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=false,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:38,524 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@e0420b:dav/validator,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=false,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:38,524 | DEBUG | queue://dav/validator expiring messages done. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | DEBUG | queue://dav/logger expiring messages .. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | DEBUG | dav/logger toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 1, dequeueCount: 1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@1c64ed8:dav/logger,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=true,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@1c64ed8:dav/logger,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=true,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | DEBUG | queue://dav/logger expiring messages done. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | DEBUG | queue://dav/synchronizer expiring messages .. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | DEBUG | dav/synchronizer toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 1, dequeueCount: 1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,824 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@1549ceb:dav/synchronizer,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=true,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,825 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@1549ceb:dav/synchronizer,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=true,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,825 | DEBUG | queue://dav/synchronizer expiring messages done. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,825 | DEBUG | queue://dav/executor expiring messages .. | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,825 | DEBUG | dav/executor toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 0, enqueueCount: 1, dequeueCount: 1 | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,825 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@9b777a:dav/executor,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=true,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2012-06-11 02:04:39,825 | TRACE | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.QueueStorePrefetch@9b777a:dav/executor,batchResetNeeded=false,storeHasMessages=true,size=0,cacheEnabled=true - fillBatch | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.AbstractStoreCursor | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
```

We can see above lines from the scheduler and suspected that it might be introducing the wait and so tried using the flag useScheduleSupport=false. We also tried persistent=false flag but it had no effect on the time.

Here is my ActiveMQ.xml file:

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" 
        useShutdownHook="false" useJmx="true" persistent="false">

        <!--
            For better performances use VM cursor and small memory limit.
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

            Also, if your producer is "hanging", it's probably due to producer flow control.
            For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        -->
  <!--
        <destinationPolicy>
      <policyMap><policyEntries>

          <policyEntry topic="FOO.>">
            <dispatchPolicy>
              <strictOrderDispatchPolicy />
            </dispatchPolicy>
            <subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
              <lastImageSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy />
            </subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
          </policyEntry>

      </policyEntries></policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
  -->

<destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="1mb">
                  <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                    <vmCursor />
                  </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="1mb">
                  <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                       For more information, see:

                       http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

                  <pendingQueuePolicy>
                    <vmQueueCursor/>
                  </pendingQueuePolicy>
                  -->
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
            If using ActiveMQ embedded - the following limits could safely be used:

        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>-->

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="default" uri="tcp://localhost:61616?jms.useAsyncSend=true&amp;jms.prefetchPolicy.all=10&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0" discoveryUri="multicast://default"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

Please help in understanding what can be the root cause for the extra delay in the response. This extra response time is causing us to fail our Production standard response time limit. Also, client times out waiting for the data, since they are configured to automatically close the connection after the time limit is reached.

Comment: how does your 5.6 activemq.xml file compare to your 4.0 activemq.xml file...many performance related variables are a result of subtle differences in this file